# Configure CDN for Rails 6 ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I have configured ActiveStorage and it works properly.

However I need to change the final URLs returned to the users, so that they use a CDN.

Currently the final image URL is:

```
https://mywebsite.nyc1.digitaloceanspaces.com/...
```

But I need this instead:

```
https://mywebsite.nyc1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/...
```

Is it possible to achieve that in Rails 6?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems not possible to configure Rails 6.0 to use a CDN at the moment... However I was able to achieve that by using:

```
variant.service_url.sub('digitaloceanspaces.com', 'cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com')
```

Comment: For anyone looking for a complete solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59107484/51387